# ALT+F4 In Xfce prompts logout if no windows are open, can it be disabled?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I believe this was considered a bug and then fixed:
https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1776

I would prefer to disable it, i.e. pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> on the desktop with no windows open should simply do nothing.

I looked around in various keyboard settings (and on Google) but couldn't find anything. Can it be done?

Comment: My reading of that bug is that it **is** intended behavior for `Alt+F4` to call for session logout if no window is open. I don't think it can be changed by the user :(

Comment: I can confirm that with Xfce4 the Alt+F4 is still there.  But if I switch my desktop to Xubuntu, it does not allow for the Alt+F4 with no windows open.